# How to display Money sign in FPDF-php

Tags: php, fpdf

Good day Im a newbie programmer, please help me about this problem.

I want to display ₱ sign in pdf but in my code is displaying "&#8369";

this is my code sir / mam

```
$a = htmlentities("&#8369;");
$b = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', html_entity_decode($a));
$pdf->Write(5,"Your amount balance is".$b."-".$balancevalue);
```

My coding is totally finish if this money sign will display.

Thanks in advance and Im very sorry if my English is too bad :)

Comment: sorry if im so noob, so you down vote my question

Comment: What are you using to create your pdf files?

Comment: fpdf po sir im using

Comment: Its cool to meet you here. Pilipino eh? I don't know much about fpdf. I use mpdf, but I'll try to help as best I can. Did you try Jevgenijs answer below?

Answer (score 0):

After you use htmlentities function, $a becomes `&amp;#8369;`, and after html_entity_decode, $b becomes `&#8369;`, not the unicode ₱ sign.

Try using this:

```
$a = "&#8369;";
```

instead of this:

```
$a = htmlentities("&#8369;");
```

Comment: sir some error encounter iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in C:\wamp\www\Monitoring\file\reportpdf.php on line 135

Answer (score 0):

When using FPDF fonts use ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252.

If the iconv extension is available, here's how to do it:

```
$a = '&#8369;';
$b = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $a);
$pdf->Write(5,"Your amount balance is".$b."-".$balancevalue);
```

Comment: mpdf hmn... kaya nia po mag anu ng pesos sign

Comment: You forgot a semicolon :) `$a = '&#8369;';`

Comment: I don't know about printing it to fpdf, but the above code prints the piso sign in my browser using xampp. PS: Let's keep our comments in English so we don't upset the rest of the users :)

Comment: Made a slight change... forgot semicolon... copy/paste and try again.

Comment: sir i just copy then paste the code the output Your amount balance is&#8369; :D.... i think i should change to other type to convert data to pdf.. :(...

Comment: You might want to try [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) It prints anything that a browser will print because it converts a web page into a pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);
```

Comment: Can you explain what that line does and how it solves the problem?